# Upload 3gpp file to a web server

Tags: android, video

My question is I have used many examples of http uploads of files for the android. They all seem to work except for video files that are .3gpp. I use the same code for .mov video files and it works OK. On the web side is just a PHP script. Does any know or have successfully uploaded a video (.3gpp) to a server? I don't get any error that I can see. The code I use also works for image files (jpg). It's just the .3gpp file type.

Thanks for any help you can give me..

Answer (score 0):

isnt it 3gp
is it possible u are giving it the wrong extension?

i would say that the method u are using to upload should be pretty dumb to what files its uploading so it should work (as u said).  the only other thing is i would try to match file size.  so do a 5mb picture then a 5min video to ensure it is the file type causing the error

i would also say that maybe the 3 in the extension could cause problems (depending on how or what is reading it)